# Mongoose static methods autocompletion in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, webstorm

When doing the following in WebStorm, I cannot get autocompletion when importing a mongoose model and trying to use a static method on the schema.

In one file I have my Mongoose schema defined with static methods:

```
 userSchema.statics.saveUser = function(callback){
        var user = new this();
        user.save(callback);
    };
```

And in another file I try to use these methods but I don't get autocompletion.

```
var User = require('../models/user.js');
User.saveUser(function(err, result) {
...
}
```

Whereas if I would type `User.statics.saveUser(...`
I would get autocompletion.

Do you know about a workaround ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not supported by WebStorm.

You can see the issue tracked [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207115889-Mongoose-static-methods-autocompletion-in-WebStorm?page=1#community_comment_207369045) with a potential workaround using JSDoc.